# Xcode : <unknown>:0: error: module name "" is not a valid identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, xctest

[image]

I keep getting this error message when I try to run UnitTest(XCTest) in Xcode. Someone says that this could be resolved by adding *PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME* to test target. But I am not able to add this the Xcode's says there's already this even I can't see it at all.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue? even very small clues would be very appreciated.